# Spell checker that will work within any Windows application

Tags: windows, language, spell-checker, english

I'm seeking recommendations for an English spell-checker ***that will work within any Windows app.***

***Required Features:***

1. Compatible with Windows 7-10
2. Ability to spell check *existing text* in a window.  For example, if I open a text file in a text editor that does not have a spell-checker, I would like to be able to check the spelling of that document.
3. Ability to add hundreds of custom words
4. Internet access not required
5. No nag screens, ads, or telemetry
6. One-time price under 15 $/€ (no subscriptions or fees for updates, please)

***Optional Preferences (not required):***

1. Portable (strongly preferred)
2. Open-source
3. Gratis
4. Ability to use various dictionaries
5. Low memory use

***Why?*** If your are curious, I'm interested in this because:

1. It takes time and effort to maintain custom word lists when every application uses its own spell-checker.
2. Some applications do not have built-in spell-checkers.
3. Almost every Windows app that has its own spell-checker uses its own base dictionary.  Thus, one app will claim a word is spelled incorrectly, while another will claim it is spelled correctly.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the suggestions given by a [Google search on "free spell checker windows"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Free+spell+checker+windows)? If so, what do you dfind unacceptable about them?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Before posting the above question, I went through over a dozen websites, and did not find a tool that meets the requirements in the question.  The only software I found that was close was tinySpell.  I regret that I no longer recall why it wasn't a candidate, so I'm going to take another look at it to try to jog my memory.

Comment: That's why I posted the comment I did - you can save yourself and everyone else some time if you tell us what you've eliminated and why.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Good idea. It was a few months ago that I spent a couple hours looking for such a tool, and I eventually stopped after finding nothing that met the requirements.  My notes from that little "expedition" are long gone, but I remember tinySpell being an "almost" match.  I think the issue with tinySpell was that, IIRC, it checks spelling as you type, but not the existing contents of the current window.  With that thought in mind, I'm going to update my question to add that requirement.  Have you ever used tinySpell, perchance?

Comment: I have not; due to a quirk of the way my mind works, I tend to underwork any spell checker, and the few applications where I do feel a need to have one available all share the same dictionaries.